# Copying to clipboard failing in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pywinauto, clipboarddata

I am currently doing an automation where I have to copy data to clipboard from UI and read that data from clipboard. I am using pywinauto for UI automation and
`app.XXXX.menu_select('Export-> to Clipboard')` is the command I use to copy data both the times to clipboard.

I am using pandas read_clipboard to read data from clipboard twice,from the same UI but in two different functions. It executes normally for the first time, but in second function , the old data is read again. I tried clearing the clipboard data using below code:

```
    from ctypes import windll
    if windll.user32.OpenClipboard(None):
      windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
      windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
```

It clears the clipboard, but then I get empty data error for the second read_clipboard.

```
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

This is the code I use, both times:

```
    df=pandas.read_clipboard(sep="\t",
                   header=0)
```

What is the possible solution for this issue?

Comment: How are you repopulating the clipboard between the calls?

Comment: @A.Leistra I am taking the data from Windows UI. I right click and select the option "Export to Clipboard". It works for both the functions when they are run separately.